# Xamarin UITests: Calabash not linked

Tags: ios, jenkins, xamarin, xamarin.ios, calabash

A little background. We currently have an iOS Xamarin app as well as a suite of automation tests via Xamarin.UITests. These tests run on my local machine fine but when running in Jenkins (remote macmini) 1 of 14 tests fail with this error:

> System.Exception: Unable to contact test backend running in app. A common cause is that the app is not properly linked with Calabash. Please verify that it includes the Calabash component

Here is what is stumping me: Why is it only failing on one test? If Calabash wasn't properly linked then all should fail. Why is this failing on our build machine/jenkins but not locally. I checked mono, xamarin and uitest versions. The ONLY difference is OS X version but my coworker runs the same version as the build machine and no failures with the tests running locally.

Not a clear cut issue but that's what I know so far. Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I figured out the problem. The app isn't being build and launched fast enough on those failure runs so the calabash server isn't running. That is what is causing the issue.